latent variables in tensorflow_probability models?
I'm trying to set up a model in tensorflow_probability.  I'm intending on using variational inference to fit the model, but I digress.
the distribution is over a d-1-dimensional space, resulting from integrating out a summary variable, similar to how the Dirichlet RV is generated.  (that is, from a product of independent gammas, reparameterize the gammas as r = sum(x), and y = x / r.
then integrating out r leaves you with the dirichlet distribution.  This is used as the kernel (component distribution) in a mixture model.
The variational model set up using the density as described (with r already integrated out) produces too few clusters, as compared to the MCMC model.  As number of dimensions goes up, we would expect the number of clusters to go up as well, but it doesn't in the
variational model.
I want to try implementing the same approach used in the MCMC model in the variational model:  sampling the latent r, and making the kernel density the 'product of gammas' as originally described.  But I do not know how to implement it in tensorflow_probability.
